# Add class to a text row with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this text generated by a WordPress plugin that is put up in a single div. See the Example below. No p tags nothing. Is there a way to add some HTML tags per row so I can style them properly?

```html
<div class="am-event-modal__description">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,

Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,
Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,

Dates: 
april 1
aprili 2
april 3
april 4</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: I did a good bit of research but I didn't find any solution of adding an HTML tag per row.

Comment: the plugin always returns the same text ?

Comment: Not the same text - it is adding the text from a couple of fields from the backend putting it together in the same HTML div.

Comment: I think @syduki answer is good

Answer (score 2):

you can split the text by new lines, then put every line in a `p` element like this:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('.am-event-modal__description');
const doc = document.createDocumentFragment();
div.childNodes.forEach(el => {
  if (el.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    doc.appendChild(el);
    return;
  }
  el.textContent.split('\n').forEach(line => {
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = line;
    doc.appendChild(p);
  });
});
div.textContent = '';
div.appendChild(doc);
```

```html
<div class="am-event-modal__description">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,

Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,
Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known,

Dates: 
april 1
aprili 2
april 3
april 4</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It does work on your script but for some reason on my modal is not working. I did add multiple CSS classes in the  .querySelector but still doesn't work.  The text is on a modal - I am thinking that it might be an issue there.